# Why in Jupyter notebook with python 3.5, only, giving SyntaxError: invalid syntax with async def?

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a virtualenv that is setup with python 3.5 only. When I am in that env.

```
$python --version #gives  python 3.5.1

$python  # in the interpreter.
>>>async def func():pass
>>>func()
```

Works just fine.
I'm working on a linux OS.

```
$ipython --version gives 4.0.1
$ipython
ln [1]: async def func():pass
ln [2]: func() # gives <coroutine object func at 0x7f57524b59e8>
```

That works just fine.

But when I start up the jupyter notebook and get in a new notebook.

```
ln [1]: async def func():pass
        func()     # gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax and points to the first line.
```

I've double checked all the spacing.  When I use the

```
!which python
```

It points to the same file used when just running an interpereter in the virtualenv terminal.

Comment: You sure you are using python3.5 in jupyter?

Comment: I've used the !which statement there it pts. to the env bin/python.  If there is a better way to check , I don't know of it.  Any suggestions?  I am a 3 kernel in the notebook and the only python I have in that env is python 3.5.1

Comment: How did you specify which interpreter to use?

Comment: When I built the env I specified it.  virtualenv -p python3.5 jupyterenv3.5. and when I activate it in the terminal that terminal showes python 3.5 as the version and also the interpreter run in that activated terminal shows 3.5.

Comment: what does `import sys;sys.version` output?

Comment: It outputs: 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) \n[GCC 4.8.4]  - which helps but is confusing.  I pip3 installed jupyter in the env and I do not have that in my global os system.  I does not have jupyter there but it does run 3.4 as its python3, as in #! /usr/bin/env python3.

Comment: what does `which jupyter-notebook` output?

Comment: In the jupyter notebook !which python outputs: /home/pontiac/mhos/Computer.mhos/Programing.computer/Python.prgmg/B.Virtual.Jupyter/jupyter3.5env/bin/python. the same as when I run which in an activated terminal. A terminal that is not activated shows my os system /usr/bin/python. for python and /usr/bin/python3 for python3.

Comment: what shebang is at the top? I also said `which jupyter-notebook` not which python

Comment: In the virtual env jupyther notebook I am not using a #!  I haven't need to.  In my other virtualenv envs that can run both 2 and 3 depending on which kernel I choose.  Those environments  where setup specifically with 2.7 and 3.4.   I will try a shebang.

Comment: The !which jupyter-notebook output is: /home/pontiac/mhos/Computer.mhos/Programing.computer/Python.prgmg/B.Virtual.Jupyter/jupyter3.5env/bin/jupyter-notebook

Comment: And the shebang at the top of that points to what?

Comment: I tried a #! (in the jupyter note book) several ways, all give 3.4.   When I use #! /home/pontiac/mhos/Computer.mhos/Programing.computer/Python.prgmg/B.Virtual.Jupyter/jupyter3.5env/bin/python3.5
import sys;sys.version gives 3.4 as its output.  I thought the #!  would seem to nail it to 3.5.

Comment: Should we move this to chat??

Comment: Leave it with me for a bit, it should be a simple matter of specifying what interpreter to use but it does not seem to be. I will have a look at how everything works in the source

Comment: Actually I think i found it,  do you have a `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3` folder?

Comment: Yes! the file contents pasted here:{
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python3",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "language": "python",
 "display_name": "Python 3"
}

Comment: That is what gets seems to get loaded, i will see if there is a way to override that with the config, you may need to `ipython kernel install` from your activated env. Adding the path to your interpreter will work i,e  `"/usr/bin/python3" -> "/home/pontiac/mhos/Computer.mhos/Programing.computer/Python.prgmg/B.Virtual.Jupy‌​ter/jupyter3.5env/bin/python"`,  I get `'3.5.0 (default, Dec  2 2015, 00:10:33) \n[GCC 4.8.4]'` after making the change

Comment: I had, in my OS system, earlier installed jupyter with sudo pip3 ( and pip) installed jupyter.  I then, in my OS system, had uninstalled them via sudo pip3 and pip.  I did it  a piece by piece manner in sudo pip3 uninstall jupyter-console...jupyter-client manner.  I'm guessing that this file got left behind??

Comment: Not sure, just changing to  `"python3"` worked for me as I use pyenv. I think once you don't specify the path it should work for whatever python is active in your  shell. So `{
 "argv": [
  "python3",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "language": "python",
 "display_name": "Python 3"
}` should work fine for you

Comment: You might be able to specify something in the config file but nothing stands out here http://jdfreder-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#options

Comment: I've tried several things. Anything like this"sudo ipython3 kernelspec install /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/pontiac/mhos/Computer.mhos/Programing.computer/Python.prgmg/B.Virtual.Jupyter/jupyter3.5env/bin/python
" outputs a Traceback ending in:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])  The only other Traceback I've got is this:ipython3 kernelspec install /usr/bin/python3.5 from "ipython3 kernelspec install /usr/bin/python3.5" 
ImportError: No module named 'jupyter_client'

Comment: You edited the .json file like I have above?

Comment: Yes. I changed, "/usr/bin/python3" to "python3"

Comment: Any way I've tried, and I've done a bunch, I get those two Tracebacks.

Comment: It works perfectly for me using pyenv, I just  pyenv local ... whatever  python3 interpreter I want and start the notebook from the shell. make sure you have the notebook installed for the version you are using though. python -m pip install jupyter

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm bused.  I look at other options after a break from it.

Comment: If you want to go with pyenv, it is as simple as setting the `kernel.json` to `python3` then    `pyenv local 3.5` (after installing it) , python -m pip install jupyter and start your notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my exchange below with Padric Cunningham, I tried Anaconda and came up with the same problem.
  I scrubbed my system of anything jupyter related.  I cleaned up my .bashrc, .pythonstartup.py and .profile of anything I thought might get in the way including changes to $PATH and $PYTHONPATH

I beleive file that was the problem was:

.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3.

I also removed a .jupyter file in my home directory that seemed to be a left over, as well as the file mentioned by Padric:

/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3 #removed via it's jupyter folder.

After the clean up I reinstalled Anaconda and jupyter notebook. Jupyter notebook now works just fine with python 3.5.1 in an anaconda virtual env.